# Datasource config for Azure Monitor datasource in kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to figure out how to configure an Azure Monitor datasource for Grafana.
What works so far is that the datasource is listed in Grafana when I deploy the stack via HELM.

[image: Azure Monitor Datasource]

This is the respective config from my values.yml:

```yaml
grafana:
  additionalDataSources:
  - name: Azure Monitor
    type: grafana-azure-monitor-datasource
    version: 1
    id: 2
    orgId: 1
    typeLogoUrl: public/app/plugins/datasource/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource/img/logo.jpg
    url: /api/datasources/proxy/2
    access: proxy
    isDefault: false
    readOnly: false
    editable: true
    jsonData:
      timeInterval: 30s
      azureLogAnalyticsSameAs: true
      cloudName: azuremonitor
      clientId: $GF_AZURE_CLIENT_ID
      tenantId: $GF_AZURE_TENANT_ID
      subscriptionId: $GF_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

Now, everytime grafana restarts, I'd need to set the client secret again.
Is there any way to configure it directly for the startup of Grafana, as well as the Default subscription being used?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the missing key:

```yaml
grafana:
  additionalDataSources:
  - name: Azure Monitor
    ...
    jsonData:
      ...
    secureJsonData: # the missing piece
      clientSecret: $GF_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
```

The client secret has to be passed via `secureJsonData`.